# I am downloading certificate of a site but when I am opening that file it is not showing any content. This is how I downloaded the cert file

Tags: java, linux, certificate, ssl-certificate

This is what I am running on my linux machine. I want to add this certificate to java keystore but I can see no content in this .cert file.

```
echo -n | openssl s_client -connect {HOSTNAME}:-1 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > ./a.cert
```

Comment: What do you see if you run just the `s_client` command on the command line?  The openssl page for s_client does not give any special meaning to port `-1`.  What happens if you specify 443 instead?

Comment: It is showing `command not found` . @JimGarrison

Comment: I meant of course `openssl s_client`...

Comment: @JimGarrison it is showing `Connection refused` and `errno=111`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the port `443`:

```
openssl s_client -connect HOSTNAME:443 2>&1 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > certfile.txt
```

Comment: actually I am writing a java program which is using getPort() method and this method is giving me output -1 as port number that's why I used -1 as port number in that command. @GAD3R

Comment: @Abhay_maniyar What do you think `getPort()` returns?  It certainly knows nothing about the remote side.  Use port 443, which is the standard SSL port.

Comment: still no content @JimGarrison